# Convert ZXing.Common.BitMatrix to bitmap Zxing in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, qr-code, zxing

Hello I need a help of Converting BitMatrix to bitmap . Here is my Code and I am using Zxing Library

```
var encodeHint = new Dictionary<EncodeHintType, object>();
String contents;
Bitmap bitmap = null;
QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
encodeHint.Add(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, ENCORD_NAME);
encodeHint.Add(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);
BitMatrix bitData;
contents = ss;
bitData = writer.encode(contents, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,100,100, encodeHint);
```

Please Note that I am making a Joined or Linked Qr Code that is a special type QR code used in Japan . Reference is [Linked QR Code](https://programresource.net/2013/05/04/2193.html) . I could make QR code using BarcodeWriter but I have to use like this way . How to convert this BitMatrix to bitMap If I use

```
bitmap = bitData.ToBitmap();
```

I got here bitmap Null And The exception is "Found Empty Contents".

Comment: the reference page is Japannese...

Comment: Yes It is Linked QR . I also tried to read using Good Translator

Answer (score 0):

This example would be applicable.
It seems that Image can be obtained by passing BitMatrix to the Write method of the BarcodeWriter class.

[File: Form1.cs Project: shuxp/test_QRCode](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/ZXing/BarcodeWriter/Encode/php-barcodewriter-encode-method-examples.html#0x81f1bb1c2116be82432493ffa4ab49fac1b932520b98133b566727da8279b9df-92,,112,)

> ```
> private Bitmap GenByZXingNet(string msg)
> {
>     BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter();
>     writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
> ...
> ...
>     ZXing.Common.BitMatrix bm = writer.Encode(msg);
>     Bitmap img = writer.Write(bm);
>     return img;
> }
> ```